# Where to find ES modules for Dexie and Dexie-Export-Import

Tags: dexie

I'm trying to upgrade dexie to the latest 3.x version on an old website (HTML, JS, CSS). It is using dexie version 3.0.0-alpha.8, Thu Jul 18 2019 and dexie-export-import.  I could not find a version for dexie-export-import, but I believe it is of the same vintage as they were both added at the same time to the website.

I was looking for the ES module versions of those files.  The file names currently in use are dexie.es.js and dexie-export-import.es.js.  I've not found anything like this on the current dexie github site.
Would they be available under different names or repos?
Thanks for the help on this.

Answer (score 0):

It has been renamed to dexie-export-import.mjs and is found under node_modules/dexie-export-import/dist/dexie-export-import.mjs

The location of the ES module can be found in package.json of a module under either the "module" field or the "exports" field. In this case, the module field.

https://unpkg.com/dexie-export-import@4.1.1/package.json

https://unpkg.com/dexie-export-import@4.1.1/dist/dexie-export-import.mjs